# How do I use my EF context in my T4 template?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I'm trying to do a fairly simple TF that would generate a list of items, but before I do that I would like to set my DBContext.  I'm trying the following:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyProj.Data" #>

<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

namespace ModelGenerator
{
<#
    MyProj.Data.ProjectContext db;
#>
}
```

> Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'MyProj' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.  I'm trying to include the project that has the .EDMX file.

```
<#@ import namespace="MyProj.Data" #>
```

In the "MyProj" project has the app.config that has a connection string called "ProjectContext.

I also have a reference in my project that contains the T4 to the MyProj.Data project.

What do I need to do, to get past this error?

**Update:**

Based off of Yacoub Massad comment.  I changed

```
<#@ import namespace="MyProj.Data" #>
```

to this:

```
<#@ assembly name="MyProj.Data" #>
```

Now I'm getting this error:

> Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'MyProj.Data' could not be
>   found

Comment: Include the assembly that contains the `ProjectContext` class via `<#@ assembly name=...`

Comment: @YacoubMassad - That didn't work.  I got another error.  See the updated question.

Comment: I guess @YacoubMassad means that you need to have both
<#@ assembly name="MyProj.Data" #>
AND
<#@ import namespace="Your.Namespace" #>

Comment: @EtienneBaudoux - I tried that too.  Same errors.  Is there a good reference for T4 tutorials?  I can't find anything other than printing out text files.

Comment: Oh I guess I got it. Try to look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962170/t4-template-adding-assembly-of-existing-project-in-solution

Comment: @EtienneBaudoux - I get what you are saying.  You have to include the .dll - I got past my initial error.  Working on different ones now.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to leave this question up as I think the assembly name information in the comments are valuable to beginners starting use T4 templates.

The answer to how to actually use your EF DBContext can be found in this question:

[T4 - Entity Framework Error: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879731/t4-entity-framework-error-method-not-found-system-data-entity-dbset1)

This question has an answer with step by step instructions.